How can I create a Heroku app in a team from the API?
I'm a member of a Heroku team, and I would like to be able to create Heroku apps programatically. I can create an app for my individual account easily enough with:
curl -X POST https://api.heroku.com/apps \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d "{\"name\":\"test-1\"}"

This fails with:
To create an app, verify your account by adding payment information.

I am a member of a team, and the team is verified and has payment information, but I have not been able to find anything in the Heroku API that allows me to specify a team when I am creating an app.
How can I create a Heroku app in a Team?

Do you have payment information set in your personal account?

@MartinBean I do not. I want to create an app in a team, and that team has payment information. With the heroku command line, I can create a project in a team without having payment information in my personal account.

You will want to use the /teams/apps endpoint instead.
